# Parent element not hiding on button click

Tags: jquery, html

I want to hide the whole `span` that contains the `button` when I click on it.
However the `hide();` call doesn't seem to do anything.

```js
$(".edit").on("click", function(e) {
  $(e.target).parent().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
   <button type="button" class="edit">Edit</button>
</span>
```

Comment: Your code works fine in the snippet I edited in to the question. Check the console for errors, and ensure that you're running the JS code after the DOM has loaded. The snippet above does this for you by default.

Comment: I just tested in Chrome and actually works fine.. but in Firefox it doesn't do anything, and I don't get any errors in the console.